# How to hide status bar when a application show the default image in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to hide status bar when a application show the default image in iOS?
as an other word,when my application load the defaul image I don't want to show the defaul image and when load finished, i want to show the image again/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    
[application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
```